# Parent and child processes and dll sharing. How does it work?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm writing an application that needs to be updated at some point. For this I'm using another process that downloads files in places to app's folder. But **sometimes** **some** files (dlls) can't be overwritten. I assume this is because they are busy.

In more detail:
The main app **A** uses lsome dlls. The updater **B** uses all the same dlls (actually not the same but copy of them in different folder). The **A** starts **B** as detached process in separate working directory. With *ProcessExplorer* or *ProcessHacker* I can see that all dlls for **A** and **B** are from different paths - there's no common path for any dll. Next I'm closing **A**. I have WaitForSingleObjectEx in **B** and I even added a timeout so I'm 100% sure that the **A** exited. I download the files to **A**'s folder (downloaded files - the dlls that was used by **A**). And it **CAN** happen that **SOME** of the dlls can't be overwritten. Every launch there's a different dll or even worse - some launches works fine! One more strange thing is that I **CAN** delete **ALL** files manually in explorer.

Is it possible that both **A** and **B** uses the same dll in memory (thought they shouldn't - every app have it's own copy)? Is it possible that some dlls are not unloaded after application exits? Why manual deleting works? What else can I do to find a reason (I tried *ProcessExplorer* or *ProcessHacker* - both programs doesn't show any criminal)?

Comment: The DLL files are unlocked when the DLL is unloaded from the process, or the process terminates. You have not diagnosed your problem correctly yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And if process terminates how many time does it take to unload a dll? Or can it happen that it will not be unloaded for some reason?

Comment: A process only terminates once. So long as there are processes that have the module loaded, the associated file will be locked. Again, you have not diagnosed the problem correctly yet. But understanding how DLLs are locked and unlocked is an important step to help you move on to making a correct diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you. And what do you mean under "correct diagnosis"?

Comment: You mistakenly think that the files are locked when no process has loaded them

Comment: You were right. The diagnosis. I spent 3 days on debugging but didn't check that files were read-only... What a shame.